# Why does my Anycubic Predator print backwards?

Tags: delta, anycubic-predator

My Anycubic Predator prints really well except for everything being backwards. Text and anything that is right or left handed comes out mirrored. The same files print correctly on other printers.

Is this a software issue or hardware?

Comment: @Mick, you should undelete your answer. It applies just fine to delta. Swapping any two motors will give the effect OP is seeing.

Comment: Thanks! I opened it up and and swapped the X and Y motor and limit harnesses and BOOM it works like it should.

Comment: @JohnCarro I have added an answer describing why you should swap steppers in relation to the used coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand coordinate system is the most used system on printers. So, when facing the front of the printer, the most common arrangement using a  is:

- X+ will move the print head to the right
- Y+ will move the print head away from you (towards the back of the printer)

For a Delta printer, when facing the printer, the Z pillar/tower should be at the back, the X tower on the left and the Y tower on the right. Do note that these tower are not corresponding to the axes movement, but are simply named as such so that you can use the designated stepper axes as indicated on your controller board. If you position the printer this way you have access between the X and Y pillars.

If the prints are mirrored in X direction, you need to swap X and Y steppers. X is the left column, Y the right.

Comment: A delta does not have X and Y steppers. It has 3 "Z" steppers spaced 120 degrees apart with arbitrary naming (I prefer A, B, and C) and by obvious symmetry swapping any two will give the effect OP described. There is not any one of the three that is "special".

Comment: I know, but the nomenclature is frequently XYZ because controller boards use XYZ (silk screen on PCB), not ABC. Not that it has anything to do with these axes. But, under the assumption I sketched placing the machine it is perfectly okay to name it as such and swapping "X" and "Y" will give the coordinate system I described. It is nice to see the product being printed is how you sliced it, not 120° either way. However, you are right, but you need to rotate the machine if you swap steppers randomly.

Comment: Ah, I understand - you mean the third axis is special by virtue of the way the printer is intended to be sitting relative to how it faces the user, and that since OP is reporting the print just as mirrored but not rotated from how they expect it to come out, it must be the first two axes that are switched.